# pip install to deb binary

Tags: package, pip, deb

So I got to install a large number of requirements from pip for production servers. Most of those requirements require python-dev and build-essential to compile.

Now the way I look at it - python-dev and build-essential comes with some overhead, and one might argue, some security issues.

To save performance on production environment, my idea is to make binary packages for those requirements.

I have found that most pip installations come with `installed-files.txt` file, listing all installed files. So it is quite easy just to pack all of the listed files to some binary package.

Now my question - is it worth it ? and is there some easier way to go around it ?
Also, maybe someone has tried it and got some helper scripts ready on `github`.
What about creating some virtual env - installing all of the dependancies and making single large binary package for all of them ?

Answer (score 3):

You can package all the Python packages as Debian Packages with `py2dsc`. See the [Debian Python Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Python/Packaging) for more details. I have done that in the last hour and it works well.